# How to avoid the undetermined form $0/0$

Tags: real-analysis

Please help me find this limit :

$$
\lim_{x\to-1}\ln\left(\frac{x^2+1-2|x|}{x^2-1}\right)
$$

I tried to multiply and divide by $x^2+1$ but I still was getting $0/0$.

Comment: Hint: If $x$ is close to $-1$, then $x < 0$ and thus $|x| = -x$.

Comment: oh and for the limit when t go to 1 ?

Comment: I don't think the limit exists. It goes to $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -1} \ln \left( \frac{x + 1}{x - 1}\right)$ which approaches $- \infty$

Comment: but the domain of definition of this function is $]-\infty,-1[\cup ]1,+\infty[$

Answer (score 1):

Since $x\to -1$ we have that $|x|=-x$, so we have that
$$\lim_{x\to-1} \ln \left(\frac{x^2+1-2|x|}{x^2-1}\right)=\lim_{x\to-1} \ln \left(\frac{x^2+1+2x}{x^2-1}\right)=\lim_{x\to-1} \ln \left(\frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2-1}\right)$$
can you conclude?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lim_{x\to-1}\ln\left(\frac{x^2+1-2|x|}{x^2-1}\right)
$$ 
since $x\rightarrow -1$, then $|x|=-x$:
$$
\lim_{x\to-1}\ln\left(\frac{x^2+2x+1}{x^2-1}\right)=\\
=\lim_{x\to-1}\ln\left(\frac{(x+1)^2}{(x-1)(x+1)}\right)=\\
=\lim_{x\to-1}\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)=\\
=[\ln(\frac{0}{-2})]=-\infty
$$